# problem on using a map function to transform a tuple on spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, jupyter

I have this tuple

```
val tuple_test = ("NCA-15","select count(*) from table")
```

What I want is to transform the tuple to keep the first value `NCA-15` AND execute the query `select count(*) from table`

This is the result I want

```
(NCA-15,8)
```

where 8 is the result of the query

I've tried this :

```
val resultat = tuple_test
    .productIterator
    .map {
       case(x: String, y: String) => (x, spark.sql(y.toString))
    }
```

but it returns

```
resultat = non-empty iterator
```

Comment: pls see my slightly different approach to achive the same result.

Comment: was it useful ? do you have any queries ?

Answer (score 0):

`select "NCA-15",count(*) from table` will give `NCA-15,8` in the form of dataframe and `.rdd` makes `Rdd[Row]` from `Rdd[Row]` you can make a tuple.

***see the below my donut example ... since I dont have Hive I simulated with temptable***

```
  package com.examples


import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}

/**
  * Created by Ram Ghadiyaram
  */
object RDDOfTupleExample {
  org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName(this.getClass.getName)
      .getOrCreate()

    val donuts = Seq(("plain donut", 1.50), ("plain donut", 1.50)
      , ("vanilla donut", 2.0), ("vanilla donut", 2.0)
      , ("glazed donut", 2.50))
    val df = spark
      .createDataFrame(donuts)
      .toDF("Donut_Name", "Price")
    //lets suppose this is your hive table since i dont have hive i simulated with temp table
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("mydonuts")
    spark.sql("select \"NCA-15\" as mylabel, count(Donut_Name) as mydonutcount from mydonuts")
      .rdd.map((x: Row) => (x.get(0), x.get(1)))
      .foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Result :

```
(NCA-15,5)
```

Comment: Busy guy I note

Comment: i have this result when i execute with my table lastException: Throwable = null
s: Unit = ()